# How to get Div Id on right click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using context menu of jquery in a page, but I am not able to pick up the id of particular div when I click the right button on this div.

Comment: Do you mean "right-click on the div" or "click on a button within the div"?

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#element').on("contextmenu",function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

or

```
$('#element').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        alert(e.target.id);        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").click(function() { console.log($(this).attr("id")); })
```

In jQuery, the object on which the event was fired is always this.

Comment: The question as I understood it was how to get the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

HTML::

```
<div id="buttondiv">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>​
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("mousedown", function(e){
       if(e.which == 3){
          var divId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
          console.log(divId);
       }
   })
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am assuming you mean "right-click on the div"</sub>

This will work on any `<div>` on the page:

```
//bind the event to the document, using the delegate of "div"
$(document).on('mousedown', 'div', function (e) {
    //check that the right mouse button was used
    if (e.which === 3) {
        //log the [id] attribute of the element that was right-clicked on
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```